# Minecraft command to set item frame content from a chest content

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft Java 1.16, I can use the `/data get block` command to get the contents of a chest:

```
/data get block -121 76 105 Items[0]
```

Which tells me that the chest has one *map#48* in the upper-left slot:

```
-121, 76, 105 has the following block data: {Slot: 0b, id: "minecraft:filled_map", tag: {map: 48}, count: 1b}
```

Also, I can use `/data modify entity ..  set value` command to set the contents of an existing item frame:

```
/data modify entity @e[x=-129,y=79,z=99,type=minecraft:item_frame,limit=1,distance=0..1] Item set value {id:"minecraft:filled_map", tag: {map: 48}, Count: 1}
```

Voila, the item_frame now contains a filled_map!

What's more, it also works if I add the spurious NBT data, like a Slot tag:

```
/data modify entity @e[x=-129,y=79,z=99,type=minecraft:item_frame,limit=1,distance=0..1] Item set value {Slot: 0b, id:"minecraft:filled_map", tag: {map: 48}, Count: 1}
```

So I was hoping to combine these commands, and set the item frame based on the chest contents using the `/data modify entity ... set from block` command:

```
/data modify entity @e[x=-129,y=79,z=99,type=minecraft:item_frame,limit=1,distance=0..1] Item set from block -127 76 105 Items[0]
```

Unfortunately, this gives an error: `The target block is not a block entity`.

I tried a few modification, by only setting the Item tags:

```
/data modify entity @e[x=-129,y=79,z=99,type=minecraft:item_frame,limit=1,distance=0..1] Item set value {Slot: 0b, id:"minecraft:filled_map", Count: 1}
/data modify entity @e[x=-129,y=79,z=99,type=minecraft:item_frame,limit=1,distance=0..1] Item.tag set from block -127 76 105 Items[0].tag
```

But again, I get the error `The target block is not a block entity`.

Is there a way to set an item frame content based on a chest slot?

Comment: This is an interesting problem and a good question.  I think there's a way to copy entity NBT data, but I'm not sure how easy that is or if it'll work in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Root cause: [PEBKAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEBKAC).

- Make sure that you use the correct coordinates
- Use NBT tags `TileX`, `TileY`, `TileZ` to select the correct target entity.
- Use `Items[{Slot: 0b}]` as source slot selector instead of `Items[0]`

```
/data modify entity @e[type=minecraft:item_frame, limit=1, nbt={TileX:-129,TileY:78,TileZ:99}] Item set from block -127 76 105 Items[{Slot: 0b}]
```

---

The most likely cause for `The target block is not a block entity` error is that you did not select the correct source block or target entity. That's what I did wrong:

```
/data modify entity @e[x=-129,y=79,z=99,type=minecraft:item_frame,limit=1,distance=0..1] Item set from block -127 76 105 Items[0]
```

should have been:

```
/data modify entity @e[x=-129,y=79,z=99,type=minecraft:item_frame,limit=1,distance=0..1] Item set from block -121 76 105 Items[0]
```

Did you spot it? Congrats to you. It took me two hours to see that the x coordinate was off: -127 instead of -121 (If you need me, I'm overthere in the corner feeling stupid)

My suggestion to others who end up here with the same issue is to:

1. Check that you can read data from the source block:

   ```
   /data get block -121 76 105 Items[0]
   ```
2. Check that the correct target entity is selected:

   ```
   /data get entity @e[type=minecraft:item_frame, limit=1, nbt={TileX:-129,TileY:78,TileZ:99}]
   ```

Especially for the target entity, note that the coordinates are sometimes off:

- Use TileX, TileY, TileX (in the nbt data) as entity selector instead of x, y, z.
- The returned Pos(ition) is slightly different: -128.5, 78.5, 99.03. Consider using `@e[x=-128.5,y=78.5,z=99,...` as entity selector.
- For /summon seems to be one-off in Y-coordinates compared to /data. To create the above item_frame entity, I had to specify y=78 instead of y=79: `/summon minecraft:item_frame -129 78 99 {Facing:3, Item:{id:"minecraft:filled_map", tag: {map: 48}, Count: 1}}`